# Biblatex: Publisher is truncated

Tags: biblatex

Im facing some problems with biblatex and some books published by the "Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics", see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{meyer_matrix_2000,
  location = {Philadelphia},
  edition = {Har/{Cdr}},
  title = {Matrix {Analysis} and {Applied} {Linear} {Algebra}},
  isbn = {978-0-89871-454-8},
  timestamp = {2015-11-18T21:19:25Z},
  publisher = {Society for {Industrial} and {Applied} {Mathematics}},
  author = {Meyer, {Carl}},
  date = {2000-06-01}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

After compilation only "Society for Industrial and Applied" is printed, the "Mathematics" term is truncated. I tried with adjusting min/maxnames, but did not help. Any further suggestions?

Comment: did you try to put all in the brackets? `{{Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics}}`

Comment: well, this works, thanks. However, this is not really a solution for me, since I'm getting exactly this bibfile from Zotero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why Zotero adds those useless braces, but with

```
@book{meyer_matrix_2000,
  location = {Philadelphia},
  edition = {Har/Cdr},
  title = {Matrix {Analysis} and {Applied} {Linear} {Algebra}},
  isbn = {978-0-89871-454-8},
  timestamp = {2015-11-18T21:19:25Z},
  publisher = {Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
  author = {Meyer, Carl},
  date = {2000-06-01}
}
```

I get the expected result:

[image]

The fact that the last token disappears when braces are used seems to be a bug in `biblatex`/Biber.

When

```
publisher = {Society for {Industrial} and {Applied} {Mathematics}},
```

is used, the `bbl` file contains

```
  \list{publisher}{2}{%
    {Society for {Industrial}}%
    {Applied} {Mathematics}%
  }
```

When braces are removed, we get

```
  \list{publisher}{2}{%
    {Society for Industrial}%
    {Applied Mathematics}%
  }
```

I'm not sure why the publisher field is applied splitting at `and`, but it's documented (section 2.3.4). If

```
publisher = {Society for {Industrial} {and} {Applied} {Mathematics}},
```

is used, then the output is again as expected.

Comment: Thanks. So I will stick with some workarround until this bug is resolved

Comment: @dbacc Can you please submit a bug report?

Comment: I could. But the sourceforge site  does not allow me, since I have no rights.

Comment: @dbacc Done: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/358

Comment: This isn't a bug - publisher is a list field in biblatex by default and therefore split on "and". It is correct to use double braces to protect the whole field. You could redefine it as a non-list field using a custom data model, use a sourcemap to add the extra braces etc.

Comment: @PLK I can see it's a list; but what about the token disappearing? Usually a publisher name is printed as a whole.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now - with double braces, nothing disappears yes? Without, it's parsed as a name list and it will lose the "and".

Comment: @PLK The problem is that with `Society for {Industrial} and {Applied} {Mathematics}` the word “Mathematics” *doesn't appear* as per the question.

Comment: Ah, I see, this is a bug.